# Django Crispy Form Doesn't Include Model ID When Using `{% crispy form %}` Tag

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

I have a Django crispy form that I'm using to update an object. I need to use a helper as follows:

```py
# forms.py

from django import forms
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Div, ButtonHolder, Submit

class QuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('type', 'instructions', 'required')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Div(
                Div(*self.fields.keys(), css_class='form-group'),
                ButtonHolder(
                    Submit('submit', 'Submit', css_class='btn-primary')
                )
            )
        )
```

And in my template I have the following:

```html
<form method='post' action=''>
    {% crispy form %}
</form>
```

My problem is that in the rendered HTML, there is no hidden field storing the ID of the Question being updated. What I expect to see is something like this:

```html
<input type="hidden" name="question-id" value="1" id="id_question-id">
```

This is strange. So I tried doing the following:

```html
<form method='post' action=''>
    {{ form | crispy }}
</form>
```

And this works. The hidden ID field is present in my HTML, and everything works perfectly. Unfortunately, this approach does not work with my form helper, which defeats the purpose of using crispy-forms. Why doesn't the ID field show up when I use the `{% crispy form %}` tag?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure to call the constructor of the base class when you override the constructor.

The [constructor in the base class](https://github.com/django/django/blob/4.2.4/django/forms/forms.py#L92) is responsible for setting up the [hidden widget for the primary key](https://github.com/django/django/blob/4.2.4/django/forms/boundfield.py#L102).

```
from django import forms
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Div, ButtonHolder, Submit

class QuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('type', 'instructions', 'required')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Div(
                Div(*self.fields.keys(), css_class='form-group'),
                ButtonHolder(
                    Submit('submit', 'Submit', css_class='btn-primary')
                )
            )
        )
```